# Unable to insert data with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making a website in CodeIgniter and for one of these pages I need to insert information into a database, however every time I enter information into my form and submit it, the page refreshes like it had been submitted but nothing enters the database.

Controller:

```
public function insertjob()
{
$this->load->helper('form');
$data['title']="Add a new job";
$this->load->view("insertjob", $data);
}

public function addingjob()
{
$jobtype=$this->input->post('jobtype');
$jobinfo=$this->input->post('jobinfo');
$this->load->model("cmodel");
if($this->cmodel->addjob($jobtype, $jobinfo)){
    $data['msg']="New job addition successful";
}else{
    $data['msg']="There was an error please try again";
}
$this->load->view("confirmation",$data);
```

Model:

```
function addjob($jobtype,$jobinfo)
{
    $newjob=array("jobtype"=>$jobtype,"jobinfo"=>$jobinfo);
    return $this->db->insert('clientjobs', $newjob); exit;
```

View:

```
</p>
<?php 
echo form_open('client/insertjob'); 
echo form_label('Job:', 'Job'); 
echo form_input('jobtype'); 
echo form_label('Job information:', 'Job information'); 
echo form_input('jobinfo'); 
echo form_submit('Add job', 'Submit Post!'); 
echo form_close(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `exit` from your model:

```
function addjob($jobtype,$jobinfo)
{
    $newjob=array("jobtype"=>$jobtype,"jobinfo"=>$jobinfo);
    return $this->db->insert('clientjobs', $newjob); 
}
```

It's not neccessary and could be breaking the database class, as well as halting any execution for the application.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
echo form_open('client/insertjob');
```

If you look at your HTML code in your browser, you'll see something like this:

```
<form action="client/insertjob">
```

There will probably be a whole bunch of other attributes in your `form` tag - they're not important for this answer.

That `action` attribute is telling the browser where to go after you click submit. Where is it going? Back to the `insertjob` method. But it needs to go to your `addingjob` method - that's where the database update is actually being done. So change the `form_open` call to:

```
echo form_open('client/addingjob');
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see your are using 2 controller functions for posting, page 1 to page 2. You have error on form open you should post your data to addingjob not insertjob.

```
echo form_open('client/addingjob');
```

will fix your issue but I highly recommend you to use, one controller for form submit. Below code will send post to same url. And you could add some attributes on it.

```
<?php 
$attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal');
echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string(),$attributes); ?>
```